# how to change datatype from string to autoincrement in Laravel?

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, database-schema

I have following schema for my migration:

```
 Schema::create('client', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('nbr', 10)->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->string('search', 100);
        $table->string('image', 100)->nullable()->default(null);
    }
```

I am trying to change string 'nbr' to autoincrements. I have tried several solutions but none of them works.I have  tried followings:

```
 Schema::table('client', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
       // $table->increments('nbr')->change();
        //$table->dropPrimary('nbr');
       DB::statement('ALTER TABLE client ALTER COLUMN nbr TYPE Integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;');
    });
```

**NOTE: i am using postgresql**

Comment: Did you try to do `$table->dropColumn('nbr');` and than simply do `$table->increment('nbr');`

Comment: @AfikDeri I tried that but i get "multiple primary keys for table are not allowed " error

Comment: I think that `$table->increment('nbr')` is primary by default, try using `$table->bigIncrements('nbr')` . Not sure but it worth the shot.

Comment: Do you need both id and nbr as auto increment?  That just seems redundant to me and I can't think of any uses for having two auto increments in one table.  If you just want nbr as auto increment, then set that as the primary key and just use a unique key for id.  Laravel's schema is made to support multiple RDBMS and most RDBMS don't allow having two auto increments columns.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new migration file and add following code. then execute `php artisan migrate`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('clients', function($table){
        $table->dropPrimary('clients_id_primary');
        $table->dropColumn('id');
        $table->dropColumn('nbr');
        $table->increments('nbr');
        $table->dropPrimary('clients_nbr_primary');
        $table->increments('id');
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::table('clients', function($table){
        $table->dropColumn('nbr');
        $table->dropPrimary('clients_nbr_primary');
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nbr', 10)->nullable()->default(null);
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesnt this drops 'id' column? I need both id and nbr column where id is primary key and and nbr is just increments.

Comment: I thought you just want "nbr" column. I updated my answer, try that one

Comment: I get "multiple primary keys for table are not allowed  " error

Comment: Try with `$table->dropPrimary('clients_id_primary');` also. (updated answer)